# convert plain string to xml format using Linux command

Tags: xml, linux, encoding

I want to convert "test@gmail.com" plain string to XML format string like `"&#116;&#101;&#115;&#116;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;"`

https://coderstoolbox.net has exact function but i want to use Linux command to encode plain string. Is there easy way to convert that string to XML format string using Linux command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo test@gmail.com | grep -o . | xargs -l1 -I{} printf "&#%d;" "'{}"
&#116;&#101;&#115;&#116;&#64;&#103;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;
```